# Upload image from iphone4 to website not working

Tags: php, iphone

First off, my website is not a public website but I want users to be able to upload photos from their mobile phones. I am using an iPhone 4 running iOS 9.x. aith the native Safari browser.

The upload form I have works perfectly from a laptop with Chrome / Firefox etc. and the form text is indeed uploaded from my iPhone but photos do not upload and I cannot see anything wrong with my code. The process of selecting a photo works correctly but the upload from iPhone appears to timeout although as mentioned the text from the form (Name, Telephone) is indeed sent. Perhaps someone can take a look and let me know if I am missing something or is this perhaps a Safari/iPhone issue (no errors). Here is the code...

```
<?php


     if($_POST['Name'] and $_POST['Telephone']){
        //info sent from form
        $Name =$_POST['Name'];
        $Telephone =$_POST['Telephone'];

        // To help protect from mysql injection
        $Name = stripslashes($Name);
        $Telephone = stripslashes($Telephone);

        $Name = mysql_real_escape_string($Name);
        $Telephone = mysql_real_escape_string($Telephone);

        $sql = "INSERT into Clients (Name, Telephone) VALUES ('$Name',    '$Telephone')";
        mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
    }

        if(isset($_FILES['image'])){
        $errors= array();
        $file_name = $_FILES['image']['name'];
        $file_size =$_FILES['image']['size'];
        $file_tmp =$_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
        $file_type=$_FILES['image']['type'];   
        $file_ext=strtolower(end(explode('.',$_FILES['image']['name'])));

        $extensions= array("jpeg","jpg","png");         
        if(in_array($file_ext,$extensions)=== false){
          $errors[]="extension not allowed, please choose a JPEG or PNG file.";
        }
        if($file_size > 2097152){
          $errors[]='File size must be less than 2 MB';
        }               
        if(empty($errors)==true){
            move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"images/clients/".$Name.".jpg");
            echo "Success";
        }else{
            print_r($errors);
        }
    }
?>

<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="" method="POST">
<input name="Name" type="text" id="ADD-CLIENT-FORMS" maxlength="50" placeholder="Name" required>
<BR><BR>
<input name="Telephone" type="text" id="ADD-CLIENT-FORMS" maxlength="20" placeholder="Telephone" required>
<BR><BR>
<input id="image" type="file" name="image" accept="image/*" />
<button id="image_alt" type="button">Image (Optional)</button>
<BR><BR>        
<input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually the above code is correct and does what it should and may be useful to others so I will leave it here. The reason I had problems was that I was not expecting iPhone photos to be bigger than the 2 megabyte limit imposed in the php part of the upload script. Well they are bigger - the photos are a whopping 3264px x 2448px and greater than 3 megabytes. My best bet is to create a function to resize the photos before they are uploaded from iPhones not only to save the user time and bandwidth but also my storage space, but this step will be another chapter.

My only advice with the above code apart from adding some more security is to use CSS to position the error warnings on the screen in such a way that they are clearly seen!

Thanks to all who may have spent some time on this....